# Display Image from XMLHttpRequest() responseText

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

I have a problem with displaying the image from the responseText.

I tried this...

`document.getElementById('myImage').src=ajax.responseText;`

NOTE: The `ajax` variable comes from `var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();`

I use the php file to get the path of the image and put it into `ajax.responseText`.

```
<?php
    echo "Pictures/The Image.jpg";
?>
```

In the output, there is no image shown. (In Google Chrome, I copied the URL of the image and when I pasted it to the text editor (such as Notepad), it has `about:blank`).

---

I tried to add `alert(ajax.responseText);` before putting it to the `#myImage`.

When I test it again, the alert shows the correct text which is the image path from the `echo` of the php file.

Next thing is I tried to display the value of the `#myimage` source...

`alert(document.getElementById("myimage").src);`

So, my code is...

```
alert(ajax.responseText);
document.getElementById('myImage').src=ajax.responseText;
alert(document.getElementById("myimage").src);
```

And then I found out that the alert shows `http://localhost/Pictures/The%20Image.jpg` which it causes the image not to be displayed.

---

How can I make the image (path returned via `ajax.responseText` from the php file) displayed to the `src` of the `<img>`?

Comment: The relative path is probably incorrect. Where is the Pictures folder present relative to the php file?

Comment: Yes, my "Pictures" folder is there. The "Pictures" folder and the php file is within one single folder.

Comment: In Chrome for example, open Developer tools using F12, click the console tab, and see if there are any errors related to the image resource.

Comment: I got an error `Not allowed to load local resource`.

Comment: That issue happens when the resource url starts with file:// instead of http://. You need to host your web app, not just open it in the browser.

Comment: @user3233089 The resource URL starts with `http://` (try to review my edited question at the second from the last paragraph). I am using `localhost`.

Comment: Use http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker to convert the image into a DATA url that xhttp can access